# matriz automática com regra python

Tags: python, matriz

Como eu criaria uma matriz de 2 colunas em python da seguinte forma.
sendo que a primeira coluna soma 0.28++ ate 100%, e a segunda é o valor da porcentagem da 1 coluna * 342.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tirando os problemas de arredondamento (que vc pode escolher como tratar melhor), é mais ou menos isso: https://ideone.com/GTstjT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para gerar essa matriz de duas colunas é bem simples, basta utilizar um laço `for` para percorrer cada porcentagem obtida e assim, realizar o seu cálculo adicionando à matriz uma lista contendo o valor obtido e o resultado de seu cálculo.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
def gera_matriz(*valores):

    matriz = []

    for valor in valores:
        linha = [valor, calcular(valor)]
        matriz.append(linha)

    return matriz


def calcular(porcentagem):

    # Edite essa função para alterar o cálculo
    return porcentagem * 3.42
```

Eu não entendi muito bem a parte do cálculo pois, multiplicando os valores por `342` você não irá obter os resultados que aparecem na tabela apresentada. Então se você quiser, basta alterar a função `calcular()` para corrigir o cálculo das porcentagens.

De bônus, abaixo está um simples código para imprimir aquela tabela formatada:

```
def formatar(numero):
    numero = "%.2f" % numero
    numero = numero.replace(".", ",")
    return numero


matriz = gera_matriz(0.0, 0.28, 0.56, 0.83)

print("-----  ----")

for linha in matriz: 
    print(formatar(linha[0]) + "%" + "  " + formatar(linha[1]))
```

---

Acima eu escrevi um código bem simples já que você parece ser iniciante na linguagem Python, mas se você quiser diminuir mais algumas linhas e deixar o código mais bonito, você pode utilizar *list comprehension* para fazer o mesmo de antes só que melhor.

Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
def gera_matriz(*valores):
    return [[valor, calcular(valor)] for valor in valores]
```

Muito menor e mais bonito que antes não é mesmo ? :)

> Veja online o código que eu fiz: https://repl.it/repls/FluffySaddlebrownCleaninstall